# How to Create a dynamic pages in Active reports 6 using C# winforms?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, activereports, componentone

I have created a Report using ACTIVE REPORTS.i have some data in XML i have to load it dynamically and once the data is loading.i have to create pages as per the data in xml.

I dont have to use manual data. Everything in my code should be dynamic except columns.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<services xmlns="">
<data downloadeddate="4/25/2014 06:38:52">
<addorupdate>
<Node1>
<Sl>2337</Sl>
<A_N>12541</A_N>
   </Node1>
 <Node2>
   <Sl>2338</Sl>
<A_N>12542</A_N>
 </Node2>
 <Node3>
<Sl>2339</Sl>
<A_N>12543</A_N>
 </Node3>
 <Node4>
<Sl>2340</Sl>
<A_N>12544</A_N>
</Node4>
 </addorupdate>
</data>
</services>
```

I have to create 5 pages dynamically to show 5 data on reports.how it can be possible..nodes can be increased to 'N' size...please help in this..i dont know how to create a new page and how to load the data aftrer First page

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding goes, you wish to display each record on a new page. The number of records may vary from 5 to 'n’.

Hence, the best suggestion would be to set the 'NewPage’ property of Detail Section to 'After’. On doing so, each record would be rendered on a new page irrespective of the number of records.

Regards,
Mohita

Comment: I tried Mohitha but its not working please see the link below   http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/how-to-add-dynamics-pages-to-active-reports-in-c-windows-forms/#post-618830